# How to invalidate the user's local cache after I deploy my build to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, caching, vercel

So I've been building and deploying my React webapp to Vercel and trying it out on Edge. However, today I decided to try it out on Chrome, so I type in the URL, press enter, then to my horror see that it's displaying the webapp as it was more than one year ago! This is because that was the last time that I used Chrome. If I hard refresh the page, it goes back to the latest version of my webapp. This must mean that I was seeing a cached version of the site.

But that got me thinking, since I get about 2000+ unique users a day, surely there were a lot of people who kept seeing a cached version, thought nobody was maintaining it, then never came back. How do I invalidate everyone's local cache?